# Merge sort for prime number of elements?

Tags: c, sorting, python-2.7, mergesort

As far as I know, In merge sort, we have to divide elements in a number of groups.
But if number are primes, then how is division possible? Do we divide them in unequal groups?
If you are going to present an implementation, please do it in C or Python.

Comment: "Give me source codes" questions aren't what we do here. Check out freelancer. Alternatively if you have theoretical issues check on programmers.stackexchange or similar.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Say you've got a set of 17 elements. You can still divide that number by 5 and hence create 4 groups: 17/5 = 3 groups of 5 elements plus 1 group of 2 elements.

Comment: I wasn't asking for the implementation. What I said is that I won't be able to understand if you explain it using Java or other languages. Luckily, no specific language was required to help. Sorry if I broke "your" rules.

Answer (score 3):

Merge sort does not require you to split your list into equally sized groups. In any properly written merge code, it shouldn't matter at all if the groups are slightly different sizes.

You'll usually want them to be close to the same size (to divide the effort evenly, reducing the sort's complexity), but even that is not strictly necessary. The basic merge-sort algorithm will work even if you divide a length-N sequence into length-1 and length-(N-1) subsequences (though performance will be lousy).

Answer (score 0):

Say there are 2k + 1, it will be split to two parts, k and k+1

Answer (score 0):

The elements are not necessarily divided evenly, but letting each group have as fewer elements as possible would get the smallest overall complexity.

This is the general principle for m-way merge sort, where m denotes the number of groups you are going to have.